# registerForActivityResult cancel?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using this, code below to open a file chooser, everything works except how do you 'cancel' without choosing anything, the UI doesn't appear to have a way for the user to cancel it appears the only way out is choose a file, the back button restarts the previous activity, if the back button is what passes for 'cancel' then well okay then.

```
private val getContentPrefImport = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent())  { uri: Uri ->
    val file = File( uri?.path )
    mytools.debug(file.toString())
    mytools.debug(uri.toString())
    if(uri != Uri.EMPTY) {
        mydeckio.loadDeck(applicationContext,uri)
    }  
   }
```

Comment: Hitting back to cancel something is pretty standard UI behaviour! And you should expect your activity to restart, there's no guarantee it'll get kept in memory while another activity you've launched is doing its thing. The docs explain it (and why you need to always register the callback immediately): https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#register

Comment: Yes the several SAF gui's have no Cancel button.

Comment: Right okay, that explains that behavior then I'll put this down to too much Windows Programing where a file chooser always has an "Ok" and "Cancel"

Comment: That's said 'back' in this case just goes up directories, it doesn't actually go back to the Activitiy.